# Target arrows Highlight for first time users in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android

Does anyone knows a library or a method I can create arrows targeting a view, for example an arrow pointing to a text view with something written on top of it.

I want this in order to make a tutorial for first time users in my app. The idea is like showing them what they can do in my app

Something like this library: http://worker8.github.io/TourGuide/#/ but in java and not kotlin

Answer (score 0):

See the android showcase view https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7438 it has all you need here

```
ShowcaseManager.Builder builder = new ShowcaseManager.Builder();
        builder.context(ShowcaseSampleActivity.this)
                .key("KEY")
                .developerMode(true)
                .view(view)
                .descriptionImageRes(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .descriptionTitle("LOREM IPSUM")
                .descriptionText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
                .buttonText("Done")
                .buttonVisibility(true)
                .cancelButtonVisibility(true)
                .cancelButtonColor(Color.White)
                .add()
                .build()
                .show();
```

Comment: Hello! Does it work well with java? Because it is all in kotlin, right? Also, can I use arrows and not only highlight things with it?